# Wait till program opens and continue

Tags: windows, powershell

I am using a virtual desktop managing powershell script to open programs on a specific virtual desktop but i am having a proble where if the program takes too long to load it will load ontol the wrong desktop. Is there a way i can have it wait till the program is fully loaded to continue?

Here are the two files i am using:
Startup.ps1

```
. .\VirtualDesktop.ps1
Sleep 1
$Desktop1 = Get-Desktop 0 #Desktop Default
$Desktop2 = Get-Desktop 1 #Desktop To-Do
$Desktop3 = Get-Desktop 2 #Desktop Outlook
$Desktop4 = Get-Desktop 3 #Desktop Music
$Desktop5 = Get-Desktop 4 #Desktop Phone
$OldDesktop = Get-CurrentDesktop


# Open To-Do On To-Do Desktop
$Desktop2 | Switch-Desktop
start shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.Todos_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App 
Sleep 3
Switch-Desktop $OldDesktop



# Open Outlook on Outlook Desktop
Sleep 1
$Desktop3 | Switch-Desktop
start Outlook
Sleep 5
Switch-Desktop $OldDesktop



# Open Spotify On Music Desktop
Sleep 1
$Desktop4 | Switch-Desktop
start spotify
Sleep 3
Switch-Desktop $OldDesktop



# Open Samsung Dex and Your Phone On Phone Desktop
Sleep 1
$Desktop5 | Switch-Desktop
start SamsungDex
Sleep 5
start shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.YourPhone_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
Sleep 3
Switch-Desktop $OldDesktop
```

Functions.ps1

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/VirtualDesktop/1.0.0/Content/VirtualDesktop.ps1

Comment: https://mcpmag.com/articles/2018/03/16/wait-action-function-powershell.aspx

Comment: Please consider upvoting any answers you found helpful, or accepting an answer (via the checkbox) if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there aren't a lot of great options for achieving what you want. The code below *might* work.

```bsh
function WaitForProcess([System.Diagnostics.Process] $procHandle) {
    while (
        $null -eq $procHandle.MainWindowTitle `
        -or `
        $null -eq $procHandle.StartTime
    ) {
        Write-Host 'Sleeping'
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500    
    }
}

$proc = Start-Process 'Notepad' -PassThru; 
WaitForProcess -procHandle $proc
```